# Tk Tablelist, how to find currently edinting cell

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I am using `editwinpath`, which returns currently editing window path, but how to know which cell is currently editing? Has tablelist any function for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://www.nemethi.de/tablelist/tablelistWidget.html), you can register an `-editstartcommand` callback which will let you intercept the behavior so you can store the cell:

```
proc editStarted {widget row column initialText} {
    global cell
    set cell $row,$column
    return $initialText
}
$yourTablelistInstance configure -editstartcommand editStarted
```

If you need to also know when nothing is being edited, a similar `-editendcommand` option exists.